# Getting error-'General Error Mounting Filesystems' while installing ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 starter edition

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Mini 110 with 2 gb of ram and Windows 7 starter edition. However, when I try to boot from USB, the Ubuntu screen loads and then shows the message-'General Error Mounting Filesystem'. I have to press Ctrl+D to reboot, and the same process starts again until I remove my pen drive. I have tried making a Live USB from UNetBootin and the software Ubuntu suggests, downloaded from pendrivelinux.com. However, Ubuntu still won't load. I am new to the Ubuntu world and don't know what to do, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try

1. when the splash screen first comes up on boot (the screen has a keyboard and a guy in a circle at the bottom) hit enter. It will display a menu that will allow you to choose what you want to do. Hit f6 and enable all of the options except for "Free software only". Then try either "Try Ubuntu..." or "Install Ubuntu"
2. Verify the state of the USB device by taking it to another computer and trying it there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried the first option and it doesn't work... I have also tried the USB drive in 2 other PCs both running Windows 8 Consumer Preview. Doesn't work. Sorry. Please Help! :(

Comment: It shouldn't matter what OS is currently installed on the computer if you are booting from the USB drive (this happens before Windows has a chance to load). Given that you have tried multiple machines, I would guess that there is something wrong with the USB drive or the CD image that you are transferring to the drive. Try downloading the Ubuntu iso from the site or via bit torrent again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your iso download. The download must have been broken. Always compare your md5 sum after downloading. Check these links:
[HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

and:
[UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)